# Where does <model>_set come from in my Django model?

Tags: python, django

I am going through the Django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

And I am looking at the example of using the python shell with manage.py. Code snippet is copied from website:

```
    # Give the Poll a couple of Choices. The create call constructs a new
# Choice object, does the INSERT statement, adds the choice to the set
# of available choices and returns the new Choice object. Django creates
# a set to hold the "other side" of a ForeignKey relation
# (e.g. a poll's choices) which can be accessed via the API.
>>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)

# Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
>>> p.choice_set.all()
[]
```

This example is using a Poll model with a question and choice of answers, defined here:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I don't understand where the object choice_set comes from. For a question we have a group of "Choices". But where is this explicitly defined? I just seems two classes are defined. Does the models.foreignKey(Poll) method connect the two classes (hence tables)? 
Now where does the suffix "_set" come from in choice_set. Is it because we are implicitly defining a one-to-many relationship between the Poll and Choice tables, hence we have a "set" of choices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`choice_set` is put there automatically by the Django ORM because you have a foreign key from `Choice` to `Poll`. This makes it easy to find all the `Choice`s for a particular `Poll` object.

It is hence not explicitly defined anywhere.

You can set the name of the field with the `related_name` parameter to `ForeignKey`.

Comment: OK. So just to clarify - if I have a similar pair of tables Table1 and Table2 (defined as python classes in the model) then if Table2 has Table1's key as a foreign key, then there will be an object implicitly created called table2_set (with lower case "t")?

Comment: @JJG: Yes, that is correct. Although don't call them tables. Tables are what is in the database. These are called "models".

Answer (score 2):

The relationship `_set` command - in this instance `choice_set`- is an API accessor for the relationship (i.e., a ForeignKey, OneToOneField, or ManyToManyField).

You can read more about Django relationships, the relationship API, and `_set` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Answer (score 1):

> But where is this explicitly defined?

It isn't; this is Django magic.

> I just seems two classes are defined. Does the models.foreignKey(Poll) method connect the two classes (hence tables)?

Correct.

> Now where does the suffix "_set" come from in choice_set. Is it because we are implicitly defining a one-to-many relationship between the Poll and Choice tables, hence we have a "set" of choices?

Yes. It's just a default; you can set the name explicitly via [the normal mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).